# Create a timer only for admin

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, admin

I'm using Laravel and I currently have two different level of authentification : member and admin. The thing is, I would like the admin session to have a time out, but not for the member session. My users use the same computer so it would be safer if the admin could be log out after 5 min of inactivity.
I can't find a way to do this.

Any idea ?

Comment: Show us your code?

Comment: what have you tried so far? It depends how you've structured things but at a guess you could check the role the user is in and set a different timeout on the session cookie, or have the code which checks for a valid session on the server check the role and the last time they made a request, against the current time, and decide on that basis whether to log them out or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Laravel wayof doing this is through middlewares.
You can create a new middleware and do the timeout check based on the logged in user.
For more details on using middleware please see the official documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

A rough implementation of the middleware would look like the below:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    $user = auth()->user();

    if($user->isAdmin()){
        $time_elapsed = time() - session('lastActivityTime');
        if($time_elapsed > self::ADMIN_TIMEOUT){ // or wherever you store the configuration
            auth()->logout();
        }
    }

    $this->session->put('lastActivityTime', time());
    return $next($request);
}
```